# Can I install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Lenovo Ideapad S510p

Tags: system-installation, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Ideapad S510p (59-411351) Laptop (4th Gen Ci3/ 8GB/ 1TB/ Win8.1/ 2GB Graph). Can I install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it? Any specific steps I need to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course you can.
Ubuntu can be installed on any laptop.
The only steps you have to follow are normal ones which you can easily google